# Quando é interessante desnormalizar o banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, normalização

Existe alguma situação em que ter o banco de dados **desnormalizado** é mais interessante que tê-lo **normalizado**?

## Por exemplo

### Normalizado

```
  Pessoas                  Cidades
| nome    | cidade_id |  | id | nome        | 
-----------------------  --------------------
| Fulano  |         1 |  |  1 | Nova Iorque |
| Ciclano |         1 |
```

### Desnormalizado

```
  Pessoas
| nome    | cidade      |
-------------------------
| Fulano  | Nova Iorque |
| Ciclano | Nova Iorque |
```

Em algum momento o segundo caso é mais apropriado que o primeiro?

Comment: Seria legal você explicar na questão como você define o que é um banco normalizado e um desnormalizado. Ajudaria tanto os futuros visitantes aprenderem, e quem for responder não teria tanto espaço para sair do foco. Deste jeito talvez esteja um pouco ampla, e dando margem a interpretação.

Comment: Segui sua sugestão @Bacco, coloquei um exemplo. =)

Comment: Eu considero a segunda parte interessante quando os dados repetem poucas vezes ou nenhuma, questão do telefone residencial, endereço (há chances de repetir os dados à mesma pessoa, porém muito pequenas para se criar uma tabela separada) e por questões de escalabilidade às vezes.

Comment: Um possível cenário que tornaria o banco desnormalizado prejudicial de forma ainda mais evidente seria quanto a localização. No segundo modelo seria necessário se apoiar num recurso secundário, como GetText, quando no primeiro bastaria, por exemplo, ter uma coluna adicional servindo de ID secundário, de repente, se relacionando com uma terceira tabela, de idiomas.

Comment: O curioso é que o segundo exemplo não demonstra uma desnormalização - ele não desrespeita nenhuma das formas normais. A saber: uma pessoa não tem nem pertence a N cidades, então a 1FN não foi violada; a tabela não tem chave primária natural composta, então é impossível violar a 2FN; cidade é de fato um atributo que descreve a chave primária (é um atributo da pessoa e não um atributo de um outro campo), logo a 3FN também não foi violada; 4ª e 5FN (mais complexas) também não foram violadas. O segundo exemplo é apenas uma repetição de texto ocupando espaço que poderia ser economizado.

Comment: Exemplo prático : Precisa se criar uma tabela customizada em um certo ERP de mercado , esta tabela é ligada à tabela de Clientes , se não for copiado o nome do mesmo o "grid" padrão não permitiria uma consulta por nome , neste caso "dona Norma" é descartada  ..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Primeiro vamos entender que *desnormalizar* não é a mesma coisa que não normalizar. ***Desnormalizar*** é um processo consciente com um objetivo claro. Um banco de dados bem normalizado costuma ser mais rápido que um banco de dados **não normalizado**. Cada forma normal é mais extrema que a outra. Reduzir de uma forma normal para outra seria *desnormalizar*? Ou seria apenas reduzir a normalização? Não sei.

Uma das maiores vantagens da [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) é facilitar a integridade de dados eliminando a redundância. *Desnormalização* precisa ser feita com muito cuidado.

A normalização se aplica bem ao modelo relacional. Não vou entrar nos casos que este modelo não se aplica bem, afinal não seria bem o caso de desnormalizar.

Eu só vejo um grande motivo interessante para desnormalizar um banco de dados.

## Performance

**Após ser medido** que o projeto físico está atrapalhando a performance e consequentemente a escalabilidade do banco de dados, **pode** ser interessante *desnormalizá*-lo com critério. Não significa que o projeto lógico deva ser *desnormalizado*.

### OLAP X OLTP

O mais comum é fazer em dados ou partes do banco de dados ou mesmo em bancos específicos para [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing). Para operações essencialmente de consulta, análise, simulação e projeção. Para aplicações de [BI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence), [Data Warehousing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse), etc.

Em bancos de dados simplificados, locais, rodando em equipamentos de baixa performance e capacidade que executam tarefas satélites específicas (terminal PDV, por exemplo) também podem se beneficiar do ganho de performance.

Note que em ambos a *desnormalização* acaba se dando mais em um banco de dados auxiliar. E quando ocorre no mesmo banco de dados, é feito em partes que são inerentemente usadas para consultas. Em atividades típicas [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) a *desnormalização* não costuma ser uma opção tão interessante.

Mas copiar dados para análise realmente é *desnormalização*? Afeta a integridade dos dados?

Não pode.

Cria dados redundantes?

Tenho dúvidas.

Não achei referências canônicas confiáveis que determinam isto. Mas alguma coisa me diz que nunca foi intenção da normalização trabalhar em cima de atividades OLAP. Quando ela foi criada só se pensava em OLTP. A minha experiência (a sua pode variar) é que *desnormalização* em OLTP costuma mais atrapalhar a performance do que ajudar.

#### Técnicas de melhoria de performance

Na verdade não são tantos casos que realmente se beneficiam da *desnormalização*. É aquela coisa da moda ou entendimento pela metade, ou ainda aplicação de algo no contexto errado. Na maioria das vezes existem outras técnicas para diminuir o impacto no banco de dados antes de ter que recorrer à *desnormalização*. Há casos que *desnormalizar* resolve um problema e causa outro.

Algumas técnicas de *desnormalização* formais:

- [Materialized views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialised_view).
- [Star Schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).
- [OLAP Cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube).

Um [exemplo no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349291/221800).

## Simplificação

Outro motivo que não é muito bom mas pode ser válido e aceitável é a simplificação do banco de dados.

Existe uma diferença entre fazer o sistema da padaria do seu Manuel e um grande sistema para uma grande empresa. Permitir uma lista de telefones no cadastro de um sisteminha pode não ser problema. Mas controlar todos os contatos de uma empresa complexa não dá muita margem para cadastrar os dados de qualquer jeito. Imagine um parceiro com vários contatos que muda de número de telefone. Você quer mudar este número de telefone, provavelmente preservando os ramais internos de todos os contatos. Vai sair mudando um a um? E se precisar pesquisar os números de telefone dos contatos? É melhor ter estes dados em uma tabela separada.

Algumas simplificações podem trazer mais problemas que soluções. Garantir a integridade de dados desnormalizados pode ser complicado e arriscado. Não é simplificação real.

#### Conveniência

Há quem diga que *desnormalizar* facilita a geração de relatórios. Mas acho que isto cai na questão do OLAP. Quer ter os dados mais fáceis para o gerador de relatório? Ok, gere um conjunto de tabelas apropriadas com os dados necessários, possivelmente de forma temporária, e disponibilize para o relatório. Se você quer apenas conveniência para acesso aos dados crie *views* ou use outra técnica que te facilite. *Desnormalização* não pode ser usada para conveniência.

#### Pegando seu exemplo

Imagine se *New York* resolva se chamar *Old York*. Dá para consertar? Não sei. Quantas cidades *New York* diferentes existem no cadastro? *New York* não é a identidade da informação, é um estado dela. Digamos que tem como consertar. Não era para simplificar? Ou será que foi apenas [XGH](https://gohorseprocess.com.br/)?

Se realmente precisa simplificar, violar a primeira forma normal é o que causará menos dificuldades. Você pode usar o tipo *array* do PostgreSQL ou uma técnica qualquer que [simule este recurso em outros sistemas de bancos de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118702/101). Só é complicado se o banco de dados usar tamanho fixo da linha. Pode haver muito desperdício. Mas questiono se é simplificação de verdade. Dá trabalho lidar com exceções.

Mas vale a máxima que se você realmente souber o que está fazendo, tudo é válido. [O problema é que quem não sabe, também não consegue avaliar se sabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

## O que parece *desnormalização* mas não é.

Existem casos em que você pode pensar que está *desnormalizando* mas está apenas adequando o projeto ao domínio.

#### Um exemplo típico.

Uma nota fiscal costuma ter uma referência ao parceiro de negócios e os itens da nota costumam ter referências aos produtos vinculados. Está normalizado e duvido que alguém ache bom *desnormalizar* a separação dos itens do cabeçalho da nota.

Se um endereço do parceiro, um cliente por exemplo, muda após a emissão desta nota, o que acontece com o endereço constante na nota? E se o preço de um produto vendido nesta nota muda?

Você tem uma bela de uma inconsistência e está fazendo algo ilegal (pelo menos no Brasil). Trazer os dados do cliente ou do produto para a nota não é *desnormalização*. É garantir o arquivamento correto da informação. Os *dados do cadastro geral do parceiro* tem um objetivo. Os *dados do cadastro do parceiro no momento da emissão da nota fiscal* tem outro objetivo. São coisas diferentes. Eles podem ser coincidentes mas sincronizá-los, tentando obter consistência, causa o oposto, torna-os inconsistentes.

A semântica dos dados do parceiro constantes na nota determina que eles são imutáveis após a emissão, então você tem que garantir isto. Copiar os dados do cliente para a nota fiscal soluciona isto (é incrível como alguns sistemas, até conhecidos, descuidam disto). Copiar os dados do produto não só é necessário pela imutabilidade. Na verdade os dados podem tomar outra forma. O preço pode ser especial para esta operação, o imposto pode ser diferenciado por alguma razão específica. E a descrição também pode ser personalizada (em uma licitação a nota deve sair com a descrição do edital e não o que o vencedor da licitação tem no seu cadastro de produtos) se tornando outra informação que usou como base o cadastro de produtos. No momento que copia o dado ele é desacoplado da sua origem. Se a informação é outra, copiar não é *desnormalizar*. Só porque você tem o número "1" em dois lugares diferentes não significa que eles representam a mesma coisa.

Mesmo assim eu sugeriria ter uma normalização destas informações. Para garantir a imutabilidade dos dados do parceiro talvez as alterações do cadastro do parceiro deveriam ser feitas em multiversão. Aí é possível se referenciar direto para a versão ativa no momento da emissão da nota. Criar múltiplas versões do cadastro pode parecer *desnormalização*. Mas se você precisa da informação repetida, se está na **semântica** do mecanismo, normalizar é impossível, qualquer tentativa neste sentido é destruir o mecanismo.

Este mecanismo tem vantagens até mesmo para resolver outros problemas e é útil em vários casos. Mas também tem desvantagens. Por isso outra solução de normalização mais pura para o intuito pode ser mais viável em outros casos.

Tenha uma tabela só com os dados necessários dos parceiros quando eles são usados em uma nota fiscal. Uma nova versão destes dados só será cadastrada se houver alterações no cadastro quando emitir uma nova nota para o parceiro. Desta forma evita-se ter cópias de dados que não são usados em nenhuma nota fiscal e ter cópias de dados que não mudam por anos. Este modelo me parece tão óbvio que me parece constrangedor que os sistemas não utilizem alguma variação dele.

Já entrei em detalhes demais sobre isto. O que importa é que o ideal é mudar a normalização e não *desnormalizar*, até porque o **requisito** do sistema usa outra informação.

#### Campos calculados

Se você está usando campos acumuladores ou outros calculados pode estar criando uma nova informação ou não. Há casos que ele é realmente redundante e cabe uma normalização e consequentemente uma *desnormalização* pode ser útil para melhorar a performance (ver primeira seção). Em casos extremos há cálculos que podem levar horas.

Mas muitos casos o campo simplesmente tem uma necessidade própria. Exemplo: deixar para um valor monetário ser convertido para outra moeda só quando você precisa é uma normalização que pode lhe trazer problema na contabilização. Este é um campo calculado que gera **nova informação**, ele não pode ser normalizado, portanto não pode ser desnormalizado.

Muitas vezes pensamos em *desnormalizar* o que não estava normalizado. Isto não faz sentido.

## Gambiarra

É, vamos ser francos, às vezes precisamos fazer gambiarras :) Não é interessante, mas necessário. Este é um motivo para *desnormalizar*.

## Conclusão

Não coloquei mais exemplos específicos porque acho que viraria lista, se tornaria muito amplo.

Quer um bom motivo para não *desnormalizar*? É difícil definir bem como fazer isto ao contrário da normalização que é um conceito relativamente simples e bem conhecido. Sem um bom domínio do SQL ou do modelo relacional e ferramentas de medição e capacidade de interpretação dos resultados, é altamente provável que a *desnormalização* piorará a situação.

Por outro lado prender-se demais à teoria para um lado ou para o outro vai trazer mais problemas que soluções. Eu poderia dizer que fazer X viola a forma normal Y e isto não pode. Mas pode trazer vantagens sem causar nenhum problema no caso específico.

Eu conheço programadores e DBAs que vão dizer o contrário de tudo isto. Eu mesmo não sigo sempre o que eu disse aqui.

Foi bom revisitar o assunto porque descobri coisas que eu não sabia. Só não postei por estar fora do escopo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Existe sim. É em um momento muito específico, que é a criação de datamarts para BI.
É o que chamam de star schema versus snowflake schema.

Vou dar minha visão de star schema pois snowflake é errado no devido contexto de datamarts para BI. Desnormalizamos para star schema, fazemos esta desnormalização de forma consciente pois existe técnicas para isso, para podermos economizar os joins e assim ganhar velocidade, puramente ganhar velocidade e economizar tempo de cpu, para o processamento de grandes quantidades de dados para famosos relatórios de BI.

Vale muito apena esta desnormalização para o contexto e usos que citei acima.

Comment: Cabe uma explicação mais aprofundada sobre alguns conceitos de BI. Embora uma modelagem Snowflake seja mais utilizada em projetos de prova conceitual, a sua aplicação em algumas dimensões de datamarts é viável sim, devido ao menor contexto onde é aplicado (uma única atividade de negócio), porém quando os dados forem convertidos ao Data Warehouse central, é interessante que a modelagem dessa dimensão seja convertida para um star schema.

Comment: Vou modificar a resposta quando tiver um pouco mais de tempo, estes dias tem sido muito corrido pra mim. Mas acho que esta havendo um engano seu pois datamart é em cima da datawarehouse e não antes, logo os dados que estão lá são normalizadíssimos. Na datawarehouse queremos os dados únicos e temporais, ou seja no tempo, 5 anos 10 anos. Datamart é depois e pode ser desnormalizado para uma melhor performance dos relatórios em cima destes dados que não são atuais, tempo real. @gmsantos, do meu ponto de vista acho que você confundiu um pouco as coisas.

Comment: Flávio, depende da arquitetura do DW. Você citou a abordagem de Inmon onde o Datamart é a interface de acesso entre o Usuário-DW. No meu comentário tomei como base  a abordagem de Kimball, onde o DW é construido por um conjunto de datamarts. Vide [Kimball vs Inmon](http://pt.slideshare.net/guest2308b5/kimball-vs-inmon) e [Arquiteturas para Datawarehouse](http://litolima.com/2011/07/19/arquiteturas-de-data-warehousing-parte-2/)

Comment: Pois é, concordamos que falamos de coisas diferentes. O que o Kimball chama de datamart o Inmon chama de ETL, nesta camada concordamos que as vezes tem dados desnormalizados, pois é o processo de normalização para o DW. Acho que entendi seu ponto de vista.

Answer (score 0):

Outro exemplo, que pessoalmete até discordo como modelo, é de um ERP de mercado que desnormaliza tabelas pois seu mecanismo de busca nas telas de sistema não permite uma busca em colunas de tabelas secundárias, por exemplo nas tabelas de títulos o nome do cliente é copiado para esta tabela quando pela normalização bastaria o código da da tabela de clientes.Para ter uma busca por nome nos títulos a coluna é copiada.

Comment: Você em muitos casos DEVE copiar dados para a tabela secundária, pois é necessário o registro do fato. Uma subsequente alteração num nome em um cadastro não pode em hipótese alguma refletir retroativamente num documento já emitido, como uma NF ou boleto bancário, assim como um produto já vendido que venha a ter sua denominação atualizada no DB após a venda precisa ter preservada a denominação original no documento correspondente. Nestes casos é muito comum a cópia de dados, a não ser que você use um DB com capacidade de pesquisa temporal (que é coisa rara de se ver em uso).

Comment: PS: Só mencionei como um contraponto. Concordo que tem muito sistema no mercado (inclusive os de uma empresa nacional de nome bem conhecido) que precisam fazer isso que você disse, mas como gambiarra mesmo, mas ai ja é um problema generalizado :D

Comment: @Bacco  Entendo o ponto mas não sei se justifica uma desnormalização, a questão poderia ser resolvida com uma versão (temporização) como você disse, confesso que nunca pensei na hipótese de fornecedor mudar de nome, não deveria haver outro cnpj e aí outro registro teria de ser criado ?! Um ponto interessante !

Comment: Pessoas, empresas, cidades, produtos, ou qualquer coisa que tenha um nome, pode ter seu nome mudado sem caracterizar mudança da entidade. A empresa também teria que mudar o CNPJ se mudasse de endereço? Em tese a única mudança que criaria nova entidade seria o próprio CNPJ. Não contaria com isto. Um governo muda a sistemática do CNPJ provavelmente forçando um recadastramento. Pronto, ferrou (pelo menos tem solução viável). Por isso é preciso tomar cuidado com chaves primárias naturais. Temporal DB não é solução para tudo. Se fosse, tomo mundo estaria usando.