# Quando usar tabela de endereços no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde várias entidades terão endereço.
Exemplo: o colégio tem endereço, o aluno tem endereço, a professora tem endereço, os fornecedores tem endereço e etc.
Estou querendo utilizar uma tabela para armazenar todo endereço utilizado no sistema. E então, toda vez que precisar de um endereço, irei me referenciar a ele pelo seu id na tabela de endereço.
Considerando que o sistema não é muito grande, essa seria uma boa forma de se trabalhar com endereços?
O que estava soando ruim, era todas essas entidades ter os campos: cidade, bairro, estado e etc.
Existe alguma melhor implementação da entidade endereço nesse caso?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22069/quando-%C3%A9-interessante-desnormalizar-o-banco-de-dados/22120#22120 Você está fazendo uma sistema para a padaria do seu Manuel ou um Mega Hiper ERP? Isto faz toda a diferença.

Comment: Não chega a ser um HIPER ERP. Mas um ERP em estado inicial. E que não será tão gigante assim.

Comment: Neste caso sim pois é comum irmãos no mesmo colégio e professores terem filhos estudando lá. Endereço como entidade na minha opinião só quando ele for relevante para a aplicação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na minha opinião, a melhor opção é ter uma tabela só de endereços, a qual se relaciona com uma tabela de bairros que se relaciona com uma tabela de cidades e que, finalmente, se relaciona com uma tabela de estados.

Entidades que possuem endereços teriam uma relação n-para-n com a tabela de endereços. Na figura abaixo dá para entender melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54606/discussion-on-answer-by-rodrigo-rigotti-quando-usar-tabela-de-enderecos-no-banco)

Answer (score 1):

Você deveria criar uma tabela de pessoas onde cada pessoa tem (alem de seus dados pessoais como nome e documentos pessoais) sua quadra,lote,numero da casa e o nome da rua ou avenida. O bairro seria o id de outra tabela bairros onde dentro da tabela bairros teria o id da cidade do bairro e depois dentro da tabela cidade teria o id do estado da cidade. Assim ficaria mais facil para nao ter dados duplicados porque poderia verificar a quadra, lote, bairro, nome da rua. A pessoa poderia ser qualquer coisa dentro do sistema como fornecedor,cliente,empregado,etc.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]