# Banco de dados deve seguir o padrão OO?

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, classes, modelagem, modelo-relacional

#### Orientação a Objeto

Segundo as Regras do OO Puro, temos:

> “O Objeto deve manipular métodos e atributos somente pertencentes a ele”

Ou seja, o que não pertence restritivamente a *class* deve ser um atributo para uma outra *class*.

#### Exemplo

```
class Pessoa{
    
    private $nome = null;
    private $idade = null;
    private $Endereco = null;
    private $Cpf = null;

    public function __construct($nome, $idade){
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->ideda = $idade;
        $this->Endereco = new Endereco();
        $this->Cpf = new Cpf();
    }
}
```

Assim a `class Pessoa` manipula apenas o que pertence à pessoa, para manipular o `Cpf` e o `Endereço` é necessário usar os métodos presentes em sua respectiva *class*.

#### Banco de Dados

Minha dúvida seria aqui. Eu não sou analista, mas gostaria de saber se em um projeto ideal o banco também deveria seguir este padrão.

#### Exemplo

```
CREATE TABLE tb_pessoa{
    cd_pessoa INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tb_pessoa_seq'::regclass),
    ds_nome VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    nr_idade INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    cd_endereco INTEGER,
    cd_cpf INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_pessoa_tb_endereco FOREIGN KEY (cd_endereco)
        REFERENCES tb_endereco (cd_endereco) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tb_pessoa_tb_cpf FOREIGN KEY (cd_cpf)
        REFERENCES tb_cpf (cd_cpf) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
}

CREATE TABLE tb_cpf{
    cd_cpf INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tb_cpf_seq'::regclass),
    ds_cpf VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT NULL
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

De uma maneira geral você **não** deve aplicar regras de orientação a objeto a um banco de dados relacional.

## CPF

Mas pra falar a verdade achei o exemplo do CPF um pouco esquisito, a não ser que tenha sido exatamente para mostrar um uso errado.

Por que precisa `new Cpf()` na classe? Não consigo imaginar um motivo. Se tiver um pode ser que faça algum sentido replicar um tratamento diferenciado no banco de dados, mas duvido que seria uma [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

#### Normalização

Foi normalizado o CPF. A normalização só faz sentido para evitar repetição, duplicidade, a redundância. Onde um CPF é redundante? Eu enxergo ele como uma informação canônica que não precisa de normalização. É claro que se ele for colocado no local errado precisaria de normalização, mas o erro já é anterior.

Um erro comum é considerar que o CPF é uma informação imutável de uma pessoa. De uma maneira geral é mesmo, mas quem garante que isto seja uma verdade absoluta sempre. Então já vi sistemas se valendo do CPF como chave primária para identificar pessoas. Aí alguém muda de CPF e o sistema está em uma sinuca de bico.

É muito complicado se valer de dados que não se tem controle para chave primária, por isto preferimos uma [chave substituta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

Pelo menos este erro não foi cometido neste caso. O CPF é uma informação que apenas compõe o cadastro da pessoa. Outro erro comum é achar que uma classe `Pessoa` representa uma pessoa, quando na verdade ela apenas representa o cadastro de uma pessoa.

## Endereço

No caso do endereço o objeto já faz um pouco mais de sentido ter uma outra entidade representando-o já que provavelmente ele é composto por vários campos. É interessante ter uma [composição ou outra forma de associação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101).

Na memória é interessante termos ponteiros para outros dados, em banco de dados nem sempre isto é interessante por razões de performance. Por isso os bancos de dados orientados a objeto não fazem muito sucesso.

Isto deve ser reproduzido no banco de dados relacional?

#### [Composição X Associação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101)

Depende. Este `Endereco` está apenas associado à `Pessoa` ou ele compõe a pessoa? Ou seja, a `Pessoa` é proprietária do `Endereco`?

Se o `Endereco` é uma entidade totalmente separada ([entendemos errado o que um endereço realmente é](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)) - afinal várias pessoas (físicas ou jurídicas) podem residir no mesmo endereço - então começa fazer sentido ter uma tabela separada.

Se o `Endereco` realmente pertence à `Pessoa`, provavelmente não faz sentido ter uma tabela separada, então você fundiria a classe `Endereco` dentro da `Pessoa` no que eu chamaria de achatamento ou alisamento da classe (*flatenning*). Isto cria uma [impedância entre o modelo relacional e de objetos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

E se a `Pessoa` puder ter vários endereços de sua propriedade? A normalização pode começar ser interessante já que se tem um número indeterminado de endereços para cada `Pessoa`. Mas note que o motivador é outro. Pode ser que a pessoa tenha um endereço de faturamento, outro de cobrança, outro de entrega, outro de manutenção e outros "criativos".

Se estes diversos endereços forem temporais, ou seja, precisa guardar os diversos endereços que a pessoa teve ao longo do tempo, provavelmente para efeito fiscal das faturas, é provável que uma tabela externa seja necessária porque o endereço precisa existir de forma independente da pessoa, ou seja, alguma outra tabela irá fazer referência ao endereço específico. Mas é possível evitar o uso de uma tabela extra, só não sei se é uma boa ideia.

#### Mecanismos do bancos de dados

Por outro lado os sistemas de bancos de dados de hoje podem trabalhar razoavelmente bem com dados múltiplos com quantidades indeterminadas. O PostgreSQL possui um tipo `Array`. Outros possuem um tipo `XML`, `JSON` ou `BSON` que facilitam ter dados assim. Mesmo quando nada disto está disponível ainda é possível [simular em cima de uma `VARCHAR` ou `BLOB`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118702/101).

Eu tendo a usar este tipo de coisa porque conceitualmente no modelo relacional um objeto que é totalmente dependente de outro, não tem vida própria, não pode ser acessado independentemente não deveria ter sua própria tabela. Muitas vezes normalizamos a tabela para separar estes objetos por uma questão de mecanismo e não de necessidade da regra de negócio.

Eu não posso afirmar que separar fisicamente neste caso está errado, algumas pessoas podem discordar de mim. Eu acho que é abusar do modelo relacional criando um gargalo - ainda que pequeno - desnecessário.

Claro que isto funciona melhor para um número quase determinado de elementos. Ou seja, se você sabe que quase todas pessoas terão entre zero e cinco ou dez endereços é uma coisa, mas se puder ter dezenas, centenas ou milhares de endereços, aí complica. E isto não é tão absurdo assim se os endereços forem temporais.

## Organizando a entidade lógica

Que fique claro, endereço é uma entidade lógica separada, isto não há dúvida, estamos analisando se ela deve ser fisicamente separada.

Mesmo quando pensamos em organizar os dados em uma entidade diferente ainda podemos fazer isto e manter na mesma tabela, pelo menos nos sistemas de bancos de dados mais poderosos. Eles permitem criar um domínio. Então você cria um tipo `Endereco` que será usado na tabela como tipo da coluna, dentro deste tipo existem outras colunas.

Do ponto de vista físico isto não muda nada na tabela, mas do ponto de vista lógico, você acessará o `Endereco` como entidade única e terá membros dentro dele como `TipoLogradouro`, `Logradouro`, `Numero`, `Complemento`, `Bairro`, `Cidade`, `Estado` e `Cep`. Se bem que alguns destes dados deveriam estar normalizados mas isto é outro assunto.

Assim você cria uma entidade separada que fisicamente será alocada na mesma tabela. Isto guarda semelhanças com o [tipo por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Até porque me parece que um endereço é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101). Note que o `Cpf` é inerentemente imutável (leia o *link* para ter certeza que entendeu o que é imutável).

Acho que esta linha de pensando ajuda definir se deve ter outra tabela ou não, mas não deve ser a única. A cardinalidade, a redundância gerada e o tipo de relação também influencia.

## Conclusão

Aí a gente começa entrar em uma discussão maior ainda se o modelo de OOP está certo. Mas nem vou entrar nisso, até porque PHP não é a linguagem ideal para querer fazer tudo certo.

Cada modelo do seu jeito.

Neste caso o CPF não merece tabela separada. Mas também não merece classe separada<sup>1</sup>.

O endereço merece classe separada e provavelmente merece tabela separada, já que podem, eventualmente, existir independentemente da pessoa - a pessoa não é dona, principalmente exclusiva, do endereço. Mas não porque pode ter vários endereços associados à pessoa.

Só dando um último lembrete: tem situações que [desnormalizar é interessante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101).

Assim como estar sempre conceitualmente correto também é uma bobagem. Tem momento para fazer o errado. Desde que saiba o que está fazendo, entenda todas as implicações, tenha um bom motivo, tudo vale.

Pode ser útil: [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101).

<sup>1</sup><sub>Talvez mereça uma classe [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) para fazer validação mas não porque precisa de algo específico associado. Precisa de uma classe no mesmo sentido que precisa de uma classe *string* para representar textos (em PHP esta afirmação fica meio esquisita já que *string* não é uma classe - mas funciona com um *value object* -, mas acho que deu para entender a ideia)</sub>

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Outro erro comum é achar que uma classe Pessoa representa uma pessoa, quando na verdade ela apenas representa o cadastro de uma pessoa." Como se representa uma pessoa então?

Comment: Não representa, isso não é possível computacionalmente, uma pessoa é complexa demais para isto, por isso que eu sempre falo que pra programar direito tem que aprender ontologia, taxonomia e até dialética.

Answer (score 6):

São definidas algumas "regras" de normalização de dados, mas estas não vem do paradigma do OO, o banco de dados deve estar de acordo com essas normas para garantir economia de espaço, manutenção, etc.

Veja mais aqui: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados

Answer (score 5):

Existem dois tipos de banco de dados:

- [Banco de dados relacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_relacional) não é orientado a objetos, para fazer bom uso desse tipo de sistema gerenciador de banco de dados você precisa conhecer e aplicar [normalização de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)
- [bancos de dados orientados á objetos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_orientado_a_objetos#Vantagens_e_Desvantagens), neste você irá persistir o objeto na forma da estrutura de dados que enviar

Então minha resposta é não, e logo na sequencia é qual banco de dados esta usando para que possa ajustar o seu objeto ao banco de dados, ou vice-versa.

Comment: eu acabei de vir de uma prova então vou analisar ainda mais a fundo sua reposta, mas o FN3 do banco relacional se parece com minha proposta.