# Modelagem para tabela de endereço compartilhado

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Possuo 3 entidades: `Ponto`, `Solicitante` e `Serviço`. Cada uma possui um endereço próprio, porém é possível que as 3 tenham o mesmo endereço.

Se uma entidade alterar o seu endereço, esta não deve alterar o endereço das outras entidades, mesmo quando possuírem o mesmo endereço.

Por exemplo: Um solicitante possui um serviço para o seu endereço atual. Quando o solicitante mudar de endereço, o serviço ainda estará relacionado com o endereço antigo.

Também é possível que vários Serviços possuam o mesmo endereço. E se o endereço de um serviço for alterado, essa alteração não deve afetar o endereço dos demais.

Dado o modelo de dados atual (abaixo), qual seria a melhor estratégia para evitar dados duplicados garantindo que nenhuma alteração afetará a outra?

[image: DER]

Comment: O que é o ponto? Existe algum motivo para o serviço ter um endereço, não basta ter só o solicitante? Me parece que no fundo não os endereços não são os mesmos, eles podem ser coincidentemente os mesmos, o que não é suficiente para o aproveitamento. Como você determina como aproveitar o mesmo endereço?

Comment: @bigown O motivo para o 'Serviço' ter um endereço e o 'Solicitante' outro, é que o endereço de realização do serviço, nem sempre será igual ao endereço do solicitante.
Ponto é um local, um pedaço de rua, que é identificado pelo endereço. Este não tem relação com o serviço nem solicitante.

Comment: Sobre o aproveitamento, não decidi ainda como fazer. Só acho estranho manter vários registros iguais na tabela endereço. Não sei se altero a modelagem para outra, ou se crio algum algoritmo para controlar isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei como vai reaproveitar o endereço já existente. Minha experiência é que isso funciona melhor no papel do que na prática, mas foi só um comentário complementar.

O que pode fazer é usar *imutabilidade*. Então se cadastra um endereço que terá um `id` de alguma forma pode ser usado por outras entidades. Até aí acho que é ok. Quando precisar mudar partindo de uma dessas entidades, a aplicação não gravará na linha existente onde os dados foram lidos, ela criará uma nova linha com os dados alterados.

Aí pense o que acontece se tiver que alterar o endereço e a alteração ter que ser aplicada para todos que apontam para este endereço. Como resolver isso? Não faço ideia. Vai deixar o usuário decidir? Não costuma funcionar, eles sempre erram nisto. E se tem que alterar em alguns pontos, mas não em outros? Confuso não é?

Aí é provável que comece proliferar novas linhas onde não deviam. Claro que pode ser que precise disso mesmo. Por outro lado se um endereço está vinculado a um serviço, então este nunca deveria ser alterado. Isso costuma ocorrer em nota fiscal por força de lei. Se por acaso o endereço estiver errado tem que usar uma retificação do endereço, não pode simplesmente ir lá e mudar o existente, ele é imutável.

Neste caso pode ser interessante:

- O endereço é cadastrado pela primeira vez no solicitante;
- o serviço é criado e usa o mesmo endereço (`id`) que está no cadastro do solicitante;
- quando o solicitante muda o endereço, faz o esquema imutável que eu falei e cria um novo endereço para ele (muda o apontamento na chave estrangeira do solicitante), mas não afeta os outros que estão usando aquele endereço;
- o serviço fica proibido de mudar o endereço. Isso significa que se houver mudança precisa ser uma retificação ou o serviço na verdade é outro (em algum caso isso pode ser relaxado).

Não entendi bem a função do ponto aí. Mas se não tem relação com os demais, não importa, só achei estranho estar na descrição da pergunta.

Leituras que podem ajudar (ou complicar :) ):

- [Banco de dados deve seguir o padrão OO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83702/101)
- [Quando é interessante desnormalizar o banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sim, @bigown você tem razão quanto ao reaproveitamento do endereço funcionar bem no papel e não na prática. Cheguei a essa conclusão. Essa solução de incluir um novo endereço a cada alteração, ficaria meio estranho, pois imagine que assim um endereço poderia ficar sem ligação com nenhuma entidade. Vou utilizar cada inclusão de endereço sendo um novo registro na tabela de endereços, não importando se já existe um igual. Pois o endereço é único para cada um de qualquer forma. Assim, se alterar, alterará somente o endereço correto.