# Relatórios - Consistência dos dados quando preços são alterados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, relatório, histórico

Tenho o seguinte banco de dados:[image: DER]

Requisitos:

- os valores das marmitas e os endereço dos clientes podem
  ser alterados de acordo com a necessidade.
- a cada semana preciso gerar um relatório desse banco de dados,
  que deve conter as informações de acordo com o momento da operação.

Problema:

Se eu modificar o valor de uma marmita, todos os pedidos feitos usando referência a essa marmita se tornarão inúteis, relatando algo que não é
correto, **fazendo o valor total calculado dos pedidos já realizados alterar** (inaceitável). então devo fazer uma escolha:

- permitindo que o relatório seja gerado no intervalo que quiser:

  1. criar outras tabelas, apenas para o relatório, onde a cada pedido salva  todas as informações duplicadas para não haver nenhuma inconsistência de preço total no relatório.
  2. não modificar os valores, apenas marcar a marmita como 'inativa' e criar outra com valor alterado, o mesmo com o cliente (retirando o telefone como chave primária).
  3. duplicar apenas os campos que mudam, no item pedido o valor da marmita, e no pedido o endereço e ponto referência do cliente.
  4. não se importar com os itens ou endereço, apenas colocar no pedido um campo Valor Total
- permitindo que o relatório seja gerado apenas de semana em semana:

  1. gerar o relatório enquanto os pedidos são realizados. por exemplo, a cada pedido acrescentar uma linha em um arquivo do Excel da respectiva semana.
  2. impedir que sejam feitas alterações, a não ser que seja imediatamente após ter feito o relatório da semana (que é salvo em outro arquivo, por exemplo planilha do Excel), e ainda não exista nenhum pedido realizado.

qualquer uma dessas opções é aceitável para meu cenário, apenas pergunto qual seria a "mais correta" (ou se pensei sobre isso de maneira totalmente errada e gerar relatório é outra coisa), já que quase todas quebram a normalização, ou o motivo de existir o banco de dados para início de conversa.

Comment: Uma pergunta um pouco grandinha para um simples almoço, em item_pedido crie mais um campo com o valor da marmita e bom apetite.

Comment: Você sabe que pode votar em tudo que existe no site, além de aceitar uma resposta nas suas perguntas? Visite o [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não temos como dizer qual é a mais correta para você. Podemos avaliar as opções abstratamente.

A segunda opção, bloqueando operações, é completamente sem sentido. É uma alternativa, mas é impor uma restrição artificial por defeito do software. Acho que não avaliou como isso é ruim.

A primeira parece ser mais adequada, mas precisa fazer direito. Se não souber como fazer ou acha que vai mudar muito, dar trabalho, então faça do jeito que achar melhor, mas pode pagar um preço no futuro.

1. O problema não é o relatório, é toda consistência do sistema. A solução deve resolver o problema de forma conceitualmente correta, ou seja, o valor da marmita não é único, e tem prazo de validade.
2. A solução é mais ou menos essa. Isso é o que chamamos de dados temporais ou históricos. Cada alteração gera uma nova marmita considerado que as anteriores ficam lá por motivos históricos. Os pedidos já realizados sempre vão referir-se à marmita e endereço do cliente efetivamente usado no momento da operação. Novos pedidos irão considerar só o marmita/cliente atual (que deixará de ser atual depois). Ou seja os dados são [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).
3. Não gosto disso, mas é uma solução simples que muitos adotam. Avalie se o esforço de fazer algo mais correto não compensa, principalmente porque nunca fez e vai ter alguma dificuldade. Pode ser uma opção. Não vai aprender fazer "mais certo", mas vai entregar o serviço.
4. Acho inviável. É gambiarra pra se livrar do problema. E nem acho que soluciona alguma coisa.

Falo disso em [Quando é interessante desnormalizar o banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101) e [Modelagem para tabela de endereço compartilhado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125667/101).