# Database modelagem, quando é possível desnormalizar

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, modelagem

Estou modelando um *database* (MSSQL) e surgiu uma dúvida. Em toda regra de negócio do clientes os dados são visualizados verticalmente ex:

- Produto,
- Preço Original,
- Preço Concorrente01,
- Preço Concorrente02,
- Preço Concorrente03,
- Preço Concorrente04,
- Preço Concorrente05
- DataLeitura

ou seja definiria logo de cara os 5 concorrentes e na pior das hipóteses teria que adicionar uma nova coluna para um novo concorrente.

Porém meu conhecimento em SQL diz que devo normalizar e colocar os dados horizontalmente, mesmo sabendo que a chances de aumentar um novo concorrente seja ínfima.

ex:

- Produto
- Preço Original
- Preço Concorrente
- Id do Concorrente;// 1= concorrente 01, 2=concorrente 02, etc
- DataLeitura

Ao fazer da forma tradicional (normalizada), já percebi que terei muito trabalho para gerar os relatórios conforme o cliente deseja, visto que várias linhas na verdade representarão apenas uma única linha para o relatório.
No SQL teria que fazer as consultas com `PIVOT`

#### Dúvida:

> Qual a forma correta nessa modelagem? Seguindo a regra de negócio do
> cliente e ai desnormalizar para facilitar ou sigo as normas rígidas da normalização? Esse é um cenário que pra mim seria uma vantagem desnormalizar.

Comment: Os concorrentes são sempre os mesmos, para todos os produtos?

Comment: não, são 5 concorrentes distintos, sempre cada produto é consutlado em 5 concorrentes.

Comment: @Dorathoto Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: ainda estou verificando...o que fazer..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma conclusão que cheguei:

> Quando desnormalizar ou não uma modelagem?

Por padrão a normalização é sempre um caminho que devemos seguir, nesse meu projeto estava claro que parecia um dos casos raros que a desnormalização até valeria a pena, por algumas regras específicas do cliente.

Então a minha abordagem foi desnormalizar. Porém tinha um parâmetro que não havia comentado na pergunta e que coloco aqui para ajudar quem quiser se aventurar por banco de dados desnormalizado.

*Tive bastante problemas ao utilizar `EntityFramework`, definitivamente ele não é feito para isso!.*

Até existe como contornar diversos problemas que estava tendo, porém as soluções eram mais monumentais do que as dificuldades que teria no caso da normalização.

**Resumo**: Vou normalizar o banco de dados (gerará dificuldades em relatórios e alguns outros pontos) **porém EntityFramework + processos assync não estão preparados para bancos de dados fora do padrão**. Pode ser que outras linguagens ou até com Ado.net em síncrono, funcione.

Answer (score 3):

De uma maneira geral o ideal é [normalizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101). Até que tenha um motivo para não fazer. Eu [já respondi sobre isto em termos gerais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101).

Nunca haverá mais que 5 preços de concorrentes? Acredito que não haverá, né?

Pode arcar com o preço de ter um pequeno espaço ocupado sem uso quando há menos de 5 preços? Acho que não é um problema. Não me parece que essa seja sua preocupação, e nem sempre devemos nos preocupar com isso mesmo. Mesmo que tenha essa preocupação, tem solução, ainda que talvez não simplifique relatórios e outras operações.

Pelos comentários, parece que não só sempre serão 5, mas serão os mesmos. Me parece um caso claro que a normalização só estará sendo feita pra seguir regra. Está desconsiderando o conceito.

Quando vai modelar tem que pensar no conceito em primeiro lugar. Lá na resposta que eu *linkei* acima fala que há casos que sequer está fazendo desnormalização, o modelo deve ser assim. Não digo que seja este o caso, mas a questão é sempre se perguntar porque está fazendo de uma forma ou outra. Não siga regras, faça o que é certo para aquele caso.

Acha que poderá ter problemas no futuro com uma mudança porque fez do jeito atual? Acho que não. Essa parte do banco de dados é usado por todo o sistema e uma mudança seria um pesadelo? Talvez seja algo muito específico usado em algo pontual.

Nunca pense no melhor modelo para o relatório porque essa é a parte fácil e que não dá problema. Mas nunca desconsidere outros fatores que podem indicar a não necessidade da regra "rígida". Não posso responder com toda certeza porque pode ter um requisito oculto aí, mas parece caso para fazer como quer mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Em minha opinião, a modelagem de dados deve ser realizada independente do [sgbd](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados). Após terminar a modelagem de dados é que vem a implementação física, quando então pode ser necessário adaptar o modelo de dados às características do sgbd.

**(1)**
Considerando-se a 3FN, poderíamos ter a seguinte implementação física no sgbd SQL Server:

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE Produto (
  ID_produto int primary key,
  Nome_produto varchar(200) not null,
  Preço money not null
);

CREATE TABLE Concorrente (
  ID_concorrente smallint primary key,
  Nome_concorrente varchar(80) not null
);
```

e

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE ColetaPreço (
  ID_produto int not null references Produto,
  ID_concorrente smallint not null references Concorrente,
  Data_coleta date not null,
  Preço money not null
);
```

Pode-se criar uma exibição (*view*) que retorne os preços de produtos em uma única linha por produto, tornando a visualização independente da implementação física.

Há vantagens e desvantagens nessa implementação.

---

**(2)**
Às vezes, por questão de performance, *[desnormaliza-se](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)* alguma entidade para a implementação física. Caso se perceba a necessidade de implementar na 2FN , pode-se então utilizar 5 colunas (uma para cada concorrente). Algo assim:

```
-- código #3 v2
CREATE TABLE ColetaPreço (
  ID_produto int not null references Produto,
  Data_coleta date not null,
  Preço_concorrente1 money null,
  Preço_concorrente2 money null,
  Preço_concorrente3 money null,
  Preço_concorrente4 money null,
  Preço_concorrente5 money null
);
```

A desvantagem desta opção é que, se resolverem acrescentar um sexto concorrente na coleta de preços, é necessário alterar a estrutura do banco de dados bem como a programação existente.

---

**(3)**
Outra forma mais radical seria armazenar a lista de preços da concorrência em uma única coluna:

```
-- código #4 v2
CREATE TABLE ColetaPreços (
  ID_produto int not null references Produto,
  Data_coleta date not null,
  Lista_preço varchar(200) not null
);
```

---

Cada uma destas opções deve vir com o respectivo conjunto de objetos de manipulação (exibição, função etc), para transformar os dados em algo simples de visualizar.

Comment: então a solução que vou utilizar é essa, horizontal, fiz uma representação simplificada lá em cima, porém nessa visão dificulta os relatórios pro cliente já que é um sistema de BI e tudo neles é vertical. quase pensando em fazer um modo que pra mim é gambiarra pra facilitar o resto.

Comment: vou estudar sobre esses termos 3fn, 2fn, valeu

Comment: sobre o código 3, não vejo o pq de ter Id_Concorrente2, preço2, poderiamos ter uma única coluna PrecoConcorrente2, e assim procurar na tabela concorrentes que é o Id=2.

Comment: No início perguntei se "Os concorrentes são sempre os mesmos, para todos os produtos?", pois estava em dúvida sobre esta parte.  ///  O concorrente 1 do produto 1 (sabão, por exemplo), é o mesmo concorrente 1 do produto 2 (pão de queijo, por exemplo)?  Ao todo, independente de produto, somente são 5 concorrentes?

Comment: sempre são iguais..