# Relacionamento em tabelas no banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados chamada `Veiculo` e a mesma possui os seguintes campos: `placa`, `renavam`, `marca`, `cor` e `categoria`.

Para a `placa` e `renavam` está tudo certo, visto que os dados são únicos.

Minha dúvida é em relação as colunas `marca`, `cor` e `categoria`. Hoje salvo tudo na tabela `Veiculo` e não faço relacionamento com outras tabelas. É necessário e/ou recomendado, através das "boas práticas", criar uma tabela para `marca`, outra para `cor` e outra para `categoria` e apenas referenciar o respectivo `ID` na tabela `Veiculo`?

O banco de dados se comporta melhor dessa forma, evitando informações repetidas?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%c3%a9-normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-banco-de-dados)

Comment: E outra aqui [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/46243)

Comment: Ou até mesmo essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22069/quando-%C3%A9-interessante-desnormalizar-o-banco-de-dados

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quando é interessante desnormalizar o banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22069/quando-%c3%a9-interessante-desnormalizar-o-banco-de-dados)

Answer (score 0):

Sim, melhor relacionar tabelas por `agilidade` e principalmente `economia de espaço`.

Por exemplo:
Todo `registro` de um carro "preto" você terá 5 `caracteres` correto ?

Se você tem uma `tabela relacionada`, seria somente a `chave` (acredito que 99 cores é muuuuuita cor, então somente 99 = 2 caracteres).

Também na hora da `consulta`, quanto mais dados maior o `processamento`.

Basicamente é isso.

Comment: Certo e toda vez que você precisar de uma cor faça um JOIN...